# Is it possible to distribute points along the glancing angles of a mesh - with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to break up the silhouette of an object, but keep the part of the mesh that faces camera clear.

[image]

Wondering if there is a way to drive point distribution with a fresnel shader similar to below. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you extract the location of the camera using an Object Info node,  and subtract your mesh's `position` attribute from it, you will get  a vector `c_vec` from each vertex to the camera.

[image]

If you normalize the vector to length 1, and take the dot-product of that with the `normal` of the surface, you have a measure of the angle of the surface to the view through the camera. The closer it is to 0, the more glancing the view. You can use some mapping of that, (`d`), to drive the density of point distribution.

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  I didn't realize relative object info could be used for a vector transform....

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help!